# Delay in drop-down menu change when hovering the Main Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, delay, menuitem

On my website [europebathroom.com](http://europebathroom.com) I have a horizontal main menu. When I hover over one of the menu-items a dropdown  appears. When I hover over another menu-item the drop-down  of that menu-item appears, as it should of course.

However, I don't want this to happen when you accidentaly quickly touch another menu-item.

I want it to be like the horizontal menu on the following link: [badkamerwinkel.nl](http://badkamerwinkel.nl).

So, there should be a delay in the change of the dropdown  by some milliseconds on hover, to avoid annoying situations if you accidentaly touch another menu-item.
Is there a script I can use to do this? I am not very experienced yet, my apologies.

Thank you so much in advance, and please know this is my first post on this great support site, so any criticism and tips are welcome to make my next posts better!

Mike

**EDIT:**
The menu works approximately like the menu below.

```
<ul class="main">
    <li class="item1">
        <div class="submenu1">...</div>
    </li>
    <li class="item2">
        <div class="submenu2">...</div>
    </li>
    <li class="item3">
        <div class="submenu3">...</div>
    </li>
</ul>

.submenu1{
    display:none;
}

.main .item1:hover .submenu1{
    display:block;
}

.submenu2{
    display:none;
}

.main .item2:hover .submenu2{
    display:block;
}
```

So if you hover item1 the submenu1 shows, if you hover item2 the submenu2 shows immediately. Is there a way to delay this action by a few milliseconds? Thanks!

Comment: sample code showing how your menu hover works atm would help

Comment: Added similar code! Just for the idea of how I want it to work. Original menu is created by a Joomla plugin so I have no idea which code I should provide. Sorry and thanks ;)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery hoverIntent plugin to delay the animations. I have used this to create a similar kind of behavior.

check it out [here](https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent)